# What's wrong with this code for adding a class to an element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, addclass

When the page has loaded, I want to add a class to an element with an ID of `contact_page`:

```
<a id="contact_page">Contact</a>
```

This is the JavaScript code I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("contact_page").addClass('selected');
});
```

It should be adding the class, but [when I run it, nothing happens](http://jsfiddle.net/S4aAx/3/).

**What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use # to select an id in jquery

```
$("#contact_page").addClass('selected');
```

See example here http://jsfiddle.net/S4aAx/7/ also you do not need to add document ready or script in jsfidle it does it for you.

Comment: Wow forgot that. Ughh I hate myself.

Comment: @Akyl I think we've all done that at one point or another

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S4aAx/6/). Essentially, you need the following:

```
$('#contact_page').addClass('selected');
```

jsFiddle already has a function for DOM ready so you can eliminate that for the purposes fo the fiddle. Next, you need to include the `#` to denote that the selector is an id.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle updated http://jsfiddle.net/S4aAx/9/

`#` was missing and

```
<script> 
</script>
```

was not needed in jsfiddle